# Make memory and free memory of 3D array in C

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner for C. I was given an example of making memory of 2D array that I have been always used. The example is as follow:

```
    complex** calloc_com2d(int value1, int value2){
  complex **c;
  int i;

  c = (complex**)calloc(value1, sizeof(complex*));
  if(c==NULL){
    perror("MemError.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  for(i=0; i<value1; i++){
    c[i] = (complex*)calloc(value2, sizeof(complex));
    if(c[i]==NULL){
      perror("MemError.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  return c;
}
```

The other version of making memory of 2d array is as follow:

```
complex **mat_new(int t,int r){
  int  i;
  complex **tmp;
  tmp = (complex**)calloc(t, sizeof(complex*));
  for(i=0;i<t;i++){
    tmp[i] = (complex*)calloc(r, sizeof(complex));
  }
  // MEM+=2;
  return tmp;
}
```

The question is I don`t know which is better to be used and if I want to creat memory for 3d array, what should I do? And what should I do if I want to free the memory of this 3D array.

I tried to write the memory of 3D array. I don't know if it goes well. I think it's not so correct.

```
complex*** calloc_com3d(int value1, int value2, int value3){
      complex ***c;
      int i, j;

      c = (complex***)calloc(value1, sizeof(complex*));
      if(c==NULL){
        perror("MemError.\n");
        exit(1);
      }
      for(i=0; i<value1; i++){
        c[i] = (complex**)calloc(value2, sizeof(complex*));
        if(c[i]==NULL){
          perror("MemError.\n");
          exit(1);
        }
        for ( j = 0; j < value2; j++) {
          c[j] = (complex**)calloc(value3, sizeof(complex));
          if(c[j]==NULL){
            perror("MemError.\n");
            exit(1);
          }
        }
      }
      return c;
    }
```

Thank you so much for reading. I would be very appreciate for your helping.

Comment: The second one doesn't check if the memory had been allocated. It also depends on whether or not the memory needs to be contiguous.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you so much for your reply. I am using the first one in my program. The parameter in the array are all value and cited so it means it's contiguous maybe? I'm sorry I'm not very sure.

Comment: They *may* be contiguous, but since the memory is allocated in multiple chunks there's no guarantee--the memory could be anywhere. This is not necessarily bad. Allocating another dimension *could* be done the exact same way.

Comment: @DaveNewton If I imitate the first method to write code, could I get the memory of 3d array? I'll try my best.

Comment: @DaveNewton I wrote one and added in the question part. I don’t know if this writing is correct.